# How can I find to access to GPUs via Tensorflow in PyCharm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I have a problem about not accessing GPU in **PyCharm** and I use **NVIDIA** as **GPU**.

I installed `tensorflow-gpu` in **Python Interpreter** of **Setting** part in **Pycharm** and then I run the code but I still cannot access it.

I wonder if I should use CUDA library? How can I fix it?

Here is my code snippet which is shown below.

```py
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

Here is the output of the code which is shown below.

```
[]
2021-06-12 23:28:52.693028: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-06-12 23:28:52.702716: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.485GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2021-06-12 23:28:52.702905: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1766] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
Please install GPU version of TF
2021-06-12 23:28:52.816304: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-06-12 23:28:52.816435: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0 
2021-06-12 23:28:52.816495: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
```

Comment: TensorFlow prints more logs than just this, particularly one where it says which libraries are missing.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Should I install NVIDIA Cuda library for this process?

Comment: CUDA is required, I am not sure why you are asking that. I was asking for the full TensorFlow log.

Comment: your error shows: `Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu` - did you check this link? On this page is even [Software requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements) which shows `NVIDIA® GPU drivers —CUDA® 11.2 requires 450.80.02 or higher.` and other tools. So you could resolved your problem few hours/days ago if you should read error message.

Comment: @furas I installed Cuda from this link: developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.0-download-archive and then run the code. I got this message (`Please install GPU version of TF`)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I installed Cuda from this link: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exe_local and then run the code. I got this message (`Please install GPU version of TF`)

Comment: I am not asking you about CUDA, you are just ignoring my question, we cannot help you if you do not cooperate.

Comment: did you install other tools from list [Software requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements)? Using Google I found on NVIDIA's forum [Does GTX 1050ti or 1650 for notebook support tensorflow-gpu](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/does-gtx-1050ti-or-1650-for-notebook-support-tensorflow-gpu/77384). Maybe this will help you.

Comment: @furas I installed cuda and cudnn but it still didn't work.

Comment: I can't help you - maybe ask on NVIDIA's forum. Maybe it need something more. Or maybe it needs older version. Or maybe it will never work with your model.

Comment: @furas I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue.

Here are the steps of solving that issue.

1 ) Download **CUDA** from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

2 ) Download **CUDNN** from https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download

3 ) Copy **bin,include** and lastly **lib** from **CUDNN** zip file and paste it C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA{version}

4 ) Then run the `.py` code in **PyCharm** and it perceives **GPU** at last.

Comment: now you can mark you answer as accepted. And few minutes later you can upvote it.